# Why DeferredResult returns 401? Spring Boot 3

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I came upon a strange issue for me. If I am calling an endpoint that returns a DeferredResult, even if when the response returned within it is 200, it arrives as 401. I also tested this with postman by just calling this endpoint, and if I call a normal endpoint, it returns the correct response.

```
    @RequestMapping(path = "/sign-document1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<?>> signFile1(){
        DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<?>> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<>(5000L);
        deferredResult.onTimeout(() -> deferredResult.setErrorResult(
                ResponseEntity
                        .status(HttpStatus.REQUEST_TIMEOUT)
                        .body("Request timeout!")));

        deferredResult.setResult(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK));
    
        return deferredResult; //this is received as 401
    }
```

```
    @RequestMapping(path = "/sign-document2", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> signFile2(){

        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK); //received as 200
    }
```

I found one single comment about this on https://spring.io/blog/2022/11/24/spring-boot-3-0-goes-ga:

> After migrating to Spring Boot 3, one endpoint with return type of `DeferredResult` now will return HTTP code of 401. After some investigation, I found out it was caused by the changes to default value of `spring.security.filter.dispatcher-types` property. This change should be documented.

answered with https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#dispatch-types

So I setted `spring.security.filter.dispatcher-types=request, async, error, forward, include`,
I still have the same issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot 3.0.0?

Comment: Yes, I am using Spring Boot 3.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spring Security 6, the authorization rules are now [applied to all dispatcher types](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/authorization.html#switch-filter-all-dispatcher-types).

In Spring Security 6.0.0, the `SecurityContextHolderFilter` [was not applied to `ASYNC` dispatches](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/11962), therefore the `SecurityContext` wasn't loaded for those requests. This problem has been [fixed](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/12368) on Spring Security 6.0.1.

The recommendation is to upgrade to Spring Boot >= 3.0.1, or, if not possible, apply [this workaround](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/11962#issuecomment-1320346945).

Comment: Uupgrading the version worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Seems that if I set `spring.security.filter.dispatcher-types` to nothing, it works. If anyone could explain me why, I would really appreciate it.